# Did Glen Gould record the full Liszt transcription of Beethoven's 7th symphony?

Tags: history, classical-music, recording, unknown-performer

*Disclaimer: My main reference for all facts in the question is wikipedia.*

In 1992 Glen Gould recorded (recording released by Sony) Liszt's transcription of Beethoven's 5th symphony. Roughly a year later (1993) he recorded the 6th symphony as well. Both of these recordings are known to me.

Recently I found the **[following youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnS1i9bVGHU)** which contains a recording of the **second chapter of Beethoven's 7th symphony** (Transcribed by Liszt of course). It sounds to me like it must be Glen Gould yet I haven't found reliable references anywhere in the internet vouching for the existence of such a recording. I desparately want to listen to the full recording (assuming there is one) but have no idea where to find it.

> **Question:** Did Glen Gould record Liszt's full transcription to
>   Beethoven's 7th symphony? If so, would it be possible to obtain a copy
>   (even if only digital) of this recording?

Comment: No way.
The performer of that recording is Jean Claude Pennetier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found authoritative sources explicitly saying there were no other recordings, but all references I know point to Gould only having recorded the 5th and the 6th. The liner notes to a CD edition of the 5th and 1st movement of the 6th explain:

> It is uncertain whether Gould actually intended to gradually record the Liszt transcriptions of the eight other Beethoven symphonies, though five months after the completion of the Fifth (on June 11, 1968), he played the complete Sixth Symphony, the Pastoral, in a CBC (Canadian Broadcasting Corporation) recital. (The recording will be issued as part of the Glenn Gould Edition, SMK 52637.) Six weeks later, however, when he was due to record the work for Columbia, he broke off the taping sessions after the first movement, which then -- in addition to various other recording projects yet unfinished -- was not issued until 1980 as part of the Silver Jubilee Album.

It seems to me that, if there was additional recordings, they would surely be mentioned in this context, so I'm convinced that the attribution to Gould of the 7th recording in the referenced youtube link is incorrect. There are a number of other (more modern) recordings of the Lizst transcriptions of Beethoven symphonies, including some complete cycles of the nine symphonies, that recording must be from one of them.

Answer (score 5):

This youtube video is misleading, as it is an [**extract of a 1987 recording by Jean-Claude Pennetier.**](https://youtu.be/Dy3oZ5jmtMw?t=15m57s)

A shame Gould did not record it though. It would have been amazing I'm sure.